# Joint cdf of extreme values

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function, extreme-value, dice

A die is rolled twice,

- $X_1$ : the minimum value to appear in the two rolls
- $X_2$ : the maximum

I would like to derive $\ F_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$.

I know that that the CDF of $\ X_1 $     = $\ 1- [1-{F(x)]}  ^  n   $,   CDF  of $\ X_2  $   $\ = $    $ \  [{F(x)]}  ^  n $
 and     $\ F_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)  = P(X_1<x_1|X_2<x_2)F_{X_2}(x_2)  $

The solution seems to be :

$\ F_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = 2F(\min[{x_1,x_2}])F(x_2) - F(\min[{x_1,x_2}])^2 $

I want to understand how such solution can be obtained.

Comment: What is $n$ here? 2? And $F$ is the cdf?

Comment: Please supply more details, is this self-study?

Comment: the example is taken from the paper "coping with copula"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work out the general answer: we have independent identically distributed random variables $X_i$, and a sample of $n$ instantiations of these RVs. I'll denote the sample maximum by $X_{max}$ and the sample minimum by $X_{min}$. Let the $X_i$ have the cdf $F$. Then we have the following:

$$ P(X_{max} \leq x \cap X_{min}> y) = (F(x) - F(y))^n \textbf{1}_{\{x \geq y\}} $$

where the $\textbf{1}$ is the indicator function. This holds because for $x\geq y$, the probability that the sample maximum and minimum are in the interval $(y, x]$ is equal to the probability that each of the $n$ random variables is in this interval.
Then to get the joint density, use:

$$ P(X_{max} \leq x \cap X_{min}\leq y) = P(X_{max} \leq x) - P(X_{max} \leq x \cap X_{min}> y) $$

$$P(X_{max} \leq x \cap X_{min}\leq y) = F(x)^n- (F(x) - F(y))^n \textbf{1}_{\{x \geq y\}}$$

If you work out what this is for $n=2$, and look at the cases $x \geq y$ and $x < y$, this is equivalent to the expression you gave.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in which working from first principles is better than specializing from poorly-understood general formulas. If $X$ and $Y$ are
the outcome on the two dice, then their joint mass function $p_{X,Y}(i,j)$ has value
$\frac{1}{36}$ for all $i,j \in \{1, 2, \dots, 6\}$ and so $p_{X_1,X_2}(i,j)$ has value $\frac{2}{36}$ if $1 \leq i < j \leq 6$, and value $\frac{1}{36}$ if $1 \leq i=j \leq 6$. The CDF can be worked out from this, but writing it out explicitly
gives a long multi-case expression that I will leave to the OP to figure out.