# Probability of sample minimum below a certain value

Tags: sampling, extreme-value

I have a list of 1000 songs with their bpm (beats per minute). If I were to sample 30 songs, is there a way to find the probability that the sample minimum is below a certain value like 100 bpm?

Comment: Are you sampling with our without replacement?  Are all songs sampled with equal probability?

Comment: All songs have the same probability of being chosen. If its possible could you explain both scenarios, when there is replacement and when there is no replacement?

Comment: The method to find the answer with replacement is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577137.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Sample minimum below a value" $T,$ say, means "all outcomes in the sample are $T$ or greater."  I will refer generally to "$T$ or greater" as your *criterion.*

Suppose $M$ of the $1000$ songs do not satisfy your criterion: that is, their bpm value is $T$ or greater.  You will have to count them: there is no general shortcut to finding $M$ based on $T.$

- **When sampling without replacement,** $\binom{M}{30}$ samples out of all $\binom{1000}{30}$ equally likely samples have no outcomes meeting your criterion.  Therefore the chance that at least one outcome does meet your criterion is $$1 - \frac{\binom{M}{30}}{\binom{1000}{30}} = 1 - \frac{M(M-1)\cdots(M-30+1)}{1000(999)\cdots(1000-30+1)}.$$
- **When sampling with replacement,** $M^{30}$ samples out of all $1000^{30}$ equally likely samples have no outcomes meeting your criterion.  Therefore the chance that at least one outcome does meet your criterion is $$1 - \frac{M^{30}}{1000^{30}} = 1 - \left(\frac{M}{1000}\right)^{30}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just started learning stats and probability from Codeacademy, so I am not familiar with what symbols like $M^{30}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} M\\30\end{pmatrix}$ mean. Are you able to show me how the calculation works in Excel or Python?

Comment: Both Excel and Python have functions for these: the first is called *exponentiation* and the second is a *binomial coefficient.*  Both are best computed with logarithms: $M^{30}= \exp(30\log M)$ and $\binom{M}{30}/\binom{1000}{30} = \exp(\log\Gamma(M+1)+\log\Gamma(1000-30+2)-\log(\Gamma(M-30+2)-\log(\Gamma(1001)).$ Excel has a log Gamma function, `GAMMALN`, and one of Python's is `scipy.special.loggamma`.